# How to post a script mysql

Tags: php, mysql

if i post a script with my cms people can not read it, it goes into the database as text

like this:

```js
<script>
   // Source: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/
   var loadCSS = function(url, callback){
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = url;
    link.id = 'theme-style';

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onerror = function(){
     if(callback) callback(link);
    }
    img.src = url;
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var initEditor = function() {
     $("textarea").sceditor({
      plugins: 'bbcode',
      style: "./minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css"
     });
    };

    $("#theme").change(function() {
     var theme = "./minified/themes/" + $(this).val() + ".min.css";

     $("textarea").sceditor("instance").destroy();
     $("link:first").remove();
     $("#theme-style").remove();

     loadCSS(theme, initEditor);
    });

    initEditor();
   });
  </script>
```

But how kan i make it that it can be read on the website?

I use this mysql query:

```html
INSERT INTO categorie (title, longstory, shortstory, date, author, categorie, type,img) VALUES('{$title}','" . htmlspecialchars_decode($longstory) . "','{$shortstory}','" . time() . "','". $_SESSION['user']['username'] ."','{$categorie}','{$type}','{$img}')";
```

I use to post a script: `" . htmlspecialchars_decode($longstory) . "`

Answer (score 2):

To escape database (string/text) input use `mysql(i)_real_escape_string`.

`htmlspecialchars` use on output, when you put this code to your site.

Comment: Hello now i get this on the website  http://i.imgur.com/KrdS21y.png

Comment: @TomLammers: use mysql_real_escape_string when you save it into database and than htmlspecialchars if you don't to to execute the code (show it on screen). If so, just write it directly from databse, without htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Tnx ;) it works, Sorry i am new :S

Comment: @TomLammers: no problem, if the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted for future readers.